# How to get cell value by cell address

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

**EDIT: Please do not bother to answer. I tried to delete the question but there are already answers. This question is invalid because get_Range() actually works. I found my problem immediately after I posted, but answerers were too quick. Sorry about this.**

How to get the cell value using the cell address? These doesn't seem to work.

```
Worksheet.get_Range("A1").Text
Worksheet.get_Range("A1").Value
```

I could get the value by

```
Worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text
```

But I want to use the cell address instead. Best if it can also interpret the full address e.g. `Sheet!A1`

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't (seem to) work"?

Comment: Did you try `Worksheet.get_Range("Sheet!A1") as Range`?

Answer (score 0):

Try sheet range value(x,y)
`Worksheet.get_Range("Sheet!A1")`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
Dim myvalue as string

myvalue = Worksheets("sheet_name").Range("cell").Value
```